# How to increase Google Colab storage

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am working on a Dataset of 70gb

Earlier using `df -BG` command

I was being shown

```
Filesystem     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on

overlay             359G    6G      335G   2% /

tmpfs                 7G    0G        7G   0% /dev

tmpfs                 7G    0G        7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/root             2G    1G        1G  44% /opt/bin

tmpfs                 7G    1G        7G   4% /usr/lib64-nvidia

/dev/sda1           365G    8G      358G   3% /etc/hosts

shm                   1G    0G        1G   0% /dev/shm

tmpfs                 7G    0G        7G   0% /sys/firmware
```

Suddenly Now it has changed to

```
Filesystem     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on

overlay              40G    5G       33G  14% /

tmpfs                 7G    0G        7G   0% /dev

tmpfs                 7G    0G        7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/sda1            46G   40G        6G  88% /etc/hosts

shm                   1G    0G        1G   0% /dev/shm

tmpfs                 7G    0G        7G   0% /sys/firmware
```

Can someone suggest any possible way to make a new Notebook with more than 300Gbs Available or any possible way to go back to previous state.

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61630092/12714318) on this other stack-overflow post for a different approach to work with COCO in Google Colab.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem. I am not sure this is a solution since I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it seems like the [Python 2 / No GPU] and [Python 3 / No GPU] runtimes have only 40GB of storage, whereas the [Python 3 / GPU] runtime has 359GB of storage.

Try changing your notebook runtime type to [Python 3 / GPU] by going to "Runtime" > "Change runtime type". Hope it helps!

Comment: That keeps changing all the time, I guess! My GPU runtime has only 68.4 GB now, while the CPU one had 107.77 GB (both 12.72 GB RAM). Someone reading it tomorrow may have still different sizes. Also, using a different account (from university) I got something like 150 GB. But nowhere near 359 GB. I think you should go for the other answer (mounting Google Drive) nowadays.

Answer (score 7):

If you pay for extra storage in google drive, you can mount drive into /content/drive/ folder

as Follows

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
> Then it will ask you for auth code
```

You can even use it for unziping datasets
**(My scenario was that I had enough space on Colab to download 18G of Coco Dataset but not enough space to unzip it)**

```
!unzip /content/train2017.zip -d /content/drive/My\ Drive/COCO/train_2017
```

Comment: Yes, and in case of COCO you can first get the bigger ZIP file, unzip and delete it, and only then do the same with validation. After deleting the zips, you may still have some space left for your results ;)

Answer (score 4):

<s>Using google drive wont work</s>, if the files are on google drive then it wont be able to read the whole directory due to too many files. From all my testing, I cant get it to work with a directory with more than 15k files in it. <s>Youll have to have enough space to download the dataset on the VM.</s>

**Update:**

I figured out how to get the whole COCO-2017 dataset into Colab with Google Drive. Basically I broke train2017 and test2017 down into sub directories with a max of 5000 files (I noticed Colab could only read somewhere around 15k files from a directory, so 5000 seemed a safe bet). [Here](https://github.com/sawyermade/detectron2_pkgs/tree/master/dataset_download) is the code for that.

Then I used rclone to upload the whole damn dataset to Google Drive, and [shared](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EVsLBRwT2njNWOrmBAhDHvvB8qrd9pXT?usp=sharing) with anyone who has a link can view.

Once you have the share in your google drive, create a shortcut for it so it can be accessed by Colab. Then I just create 118287 for train and 40670 for test symbolic links in the local directory. So far, it is working like a charm. I even save all my output to Google Drive so it can be resumed after the 12 hour kick. [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OVStblo4Q3rz49Pe9-CJcUGkkCDLcMqP) is the notebook for that.

I am training a mask rcnn now, will report results when finished but its looking pretty damn good so far.

Comment: I'd expect tfds (or google colab) would implement extracted directory to bind like  you did personally share. Thanx a lot