# My Google Colab Notebook is not using my 2TB Google Drive space

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have 2TB storage space on my Google Drive account.

I'd like to use them with Cloud Colab (GPU Python 3).

I've already mounted the Drive space but I'm still stuck with the ~69GB of Colab Storage.

(refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59513316/9726037)

**(1) Mounted the Drive space**

```
WORKSPACE_PATH = 'ml/'

drive.mount('/content/drive/', force_remount=True)
ROOT_DIR  = '/content/drive/My Drive/science'
BASE_DIR  = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, WORKSPACE_PATH)
```

**Output: Mounted at /content/drive/**

**(2) Downloaded approx 40GB of data from GCS:**

```
bucker_name = 'my_bucket_name'
!gsutil -m cp gs://{bucket_name}/* 'path_to_my_mounted_drive'
```

**Output:**

```
Copying gs://xxx/test.h5...
Copying gs://xxx/train.h5...
[Errno 28] No space left on device
[Errno 28] No space left on device
[Errno 28] No space left on device
[Errno 28] No space left on device
[Errno 28] No space left on device
[Errno 28] No space left on device
[Errno 28] No space left on device
[Errno 28] No space left on device
```

When I check the colab storage free space : I only have 3GB/69GB, instead of 2 TB...

[image: SORAGE SPACE]

What I did wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question good but i have an idea , Why don't download your data to Google drive and then access it from Colab without move it to Colab ? if can't do that , i can tell you How to do that .Don't forget to change Runtime to GPU because it's fast a little.

Comment: I don't want to download it to Colab, I want to download it to Drive and use it with Colab. But when mounting Drive, I only have access to 69GB instead of 2TB. But problem fixed, just moved to Gradient Paperspace.

Comment: Okay , great to hear that . Can you please share answer with us to learn from your mistakes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, when the drive is mounted, it need to cache the data from Google Drive. Even if you have 2TB on GDrive, you will still have the same limit as before, because the data need to be copied and cached.

So, you may need to copy a part, delete it, then copy the next parts. This may be a bit slower.

Comment: Its going to be a real problem :/

Comment: This is quite a problem. The only reason I bought extra drive storage was to use it in Colab, but I can't.

Comment: Yep! :( I still not found any solution yet, I just moved to another "notebooks as a service" provider. Hope Google will allow us to use our Drive space in collab.

Comment: @MichelDelpech Can you please let me know which "notebooks as a service" provider did you moved to

Comment: @MichelDelpech Hi! Which one did you used to solve your issue?

Comment: I've use a 3rd party provider which has shutdown this year, sorry I don't remember the name. But if you search for Notebook as a service, you'll probably find a new one. Cheers